# K8ssandra deployment has no Reaper or Grafana service

Tags: cassandra, reaper, k8ssandra

I'm pretty new with k8s and k8ssandra project.
I just deployed k8ssandra operator followed https://docs-v2.k8ssandra.io/  V2 version instruction on k8s cluster.
After that, I could not found the reaper or grafana services and pods.
What I expecting is just like what the official site said, they combined reaper and grafana into k8ssandra operator project.
Really need your help if you have any idea about this solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[EDITED]** I found out from the K8ssandra developers that the example [Single-cluster install with helm](https://docs-v2.k8ssandra.io/install/local/single-cluster-helm/) deploys a minimal cluster with the minimum components configured.

We don't have a nice procedure in the docs for deploying Reaper but you can use the [example CRD here](https://github.com/k8ssandra/k8ssandra-operator/blob/main/test/testdata/fixtures/single-dc-reaper/) to deploy it.

In relation to Grafana, they've decided not to deploy a Grafana pod with K8ssandra because the feedback that they got was that most organisations already have their own Prometheus/Grafana infrastructure. [Follow the instructions here](https://github.com/k8ssandra/k8ssandra-operator/tree/main/docs/prometheus-grafana) to deploy the Prometheus operator and Grafana.

Apologies that this isn't clear with our docs which are still being updated with details of the new K8ssandra operator. Cheers!

Comment: I installed all prerequisites, and did all thing on this page, https://docs-v2.k8ssandra.io/install/local/single-cluster-helm/.

Comment: Did you manage to get through the whole set of instructions with no issues?

Comment: no any issue while I'm following these instruction, that's why I am so confused about that.

Comment: I've got new info from the K8ssandra devs so I've updated my answer. Cheers!

Comment: @7072129 this is a completely different question to what you originally asked so please post a new question. If we respond to follow-up questions in comments, it will be a never-ending thread. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry about that Erick. I post a new question about that. Feel free to give some hint on that question.